# Как распространить действие конструкции #[...] на несколько строк?

Tags: rust

В Rust есть конструкция `#[cfg(...)]`.

Например, есть набор констант, хранящих кода цветов в терминале Linux:

```rust
#[cfg(target_os="linux")]
const BLACK: &str = "\033[0;30m";

#[cfg(target_os="linux")]
const RED: &str = "\033[0;31m";

#[cfg(target_os="linux")]
const GREEN: &str = "\033[0;32m";
```

Вопрос: можно ли как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы не нужно было перед каждой строкой писать `#[cfg(target_os="linux")]`?

Comment: На таком примере задача выглядит бессмысленной, потому что коды цветов - это характеристика не ОС, а терминала, и эти коды поддерживаются не только в линуксе, но и много где ещё (в том числе в стандартных Windows-терминалах). Наверно, можно попробовать как-нибудь перегруппировать код или воткнуть выражение с макросом `cfg!`, но в данном примере непонятно зачем

Comment: @andreymal, это не пример кода из реального проекта, здесь я просто пытался написать общий пример, демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделите платформозависимую часть в отдельный модуль. За вдохновением можно пойти подглядеть реализацию модуля `std::sys`:

```rust
cfg_if::cfg_if! {
    if #[cfg(unix)] {
        mod unix;
        pub use self::unix::*;
    } else if #[cfg(windows)] {
        mod windows;
        pub use self::windows::*;
    } else if #[cfg(target_os = "solid_asp3")] {
        mod solid;
        pub use self::solid::*;
    } else if #[cfg(target_os = "hermit")] {
        mod hermit;
        pub use self::hermit::*;
    } else if #[cfg(target_os = "wasi")] {
        mod wasi;
        pub use self::wasi::*;
    } else if #[cfg(target_family = "wasm")] {
        mod wasm;
        pub use self::wasm::*;
    } else if #[cfg(all(target_vendor = "fortanix", target_env = "sgx"))] {
        mod sgx;
        pub use self::sgx::*;
    } else {
        mod unsupported;
        pub use self::unsupported::*;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание на макрос [cfg-if](https://crates.io/crates/cfg-if):

```rust
cfg_if::cfg_if! {
    if #[cfg(unix)] {
        fn foo() { /* unix specific functionality */ }
    } else if #[cfg(target_pointer_width = "32")] {
        fn foo() { /* non-unix, 32-bit functionality */ }
    } else {
        fn foo() { /* fallback implementation */ }
    }
}
```